# How to understand the Server performance by using standard deviation in the Jmeter Summary report?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

How does JMeter calculate `Std Dev.` total value? What is it based on?

Please see the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the summary row is named `TOTAL` the values in the row aren't the sum of the values above it. Rather it is a calculated value for the entire data set.

If there are 100 samples in row1 and 100 samples in row2, the total number of samples is 200. "Total" average is the average of all 200 samples and "Total" Std Dev. is the standard deviation of all 200 samples.

`OVERALL` would probably be a better word to use in place of `TOTAL` for the summary row.

As for what standard deviation means, this isn't a JMeter measure per se, but a statistical measure of the data set. It represents how much variation or spread is present in the data set.

Comment: Thanks for reply.!                                                                                  "Standard deviation should be less than or equal to half of the average time for a label. If it is more than that, then it means that something is wrong. you need to figure out the problem and fix it." Is this statement is right?

Comment: Not always. It really depends on the nature of the data. In the case of performance measurements, it depends on the nature of the system. If say you're logging in, you expect the amount of variation to be low. Everyone logs in the same way. But say if you are searching a large database, each time you query you could be returning very different datasets, sometimes with indexes, sometimes with tablescans, the variation will be larger, response times more spread out. Talking about value of standard deviation without understand the system is shortsighted.

Comment: Then how can I understood my server performance is good or bad? give some example please.